# Is there any Antlr grammar for getting parameter name of method?

Tags: java, antlr

If I have a class like this:

```
public class Whatever
{
  public void aMethod(int aParam){

  }
}
```

Can we write antlr grammar to generate output giving information like:

```
aMethod
int
aParam
```

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java using this grammar you may also get the parameters of a method and their types  (you will have to understand how to work with it and ANTLR, consult for example "The definitive ANTLR4 reference" by Terence Parr, he has there also a Java grammar example used to parse Java source files).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is definitely: yes, we (and you) can!